# Why does part of my object not scale properly between edit and object mode?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

[image]I have created a bird and am extruding the wings from the side of the body. I have a mirror modifier set up so I can just work on one side. But the extruded shape does not stay the same when I switch back to object mode. In fact, the wings are drastically shortened and truncated and I cannot figure out why. The rest of the body is unchanged between modes.[The first image is in object mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVxHT.jpg)

[image: The second image is in edit mode.]

Comment: Does the mesh have shape keys?

Comment: I still do not understand why this is happening but I did figure out another way to do it. I just made the wing as a separate object instead of extruding it out of the body and joined it to the body using bridge edge loops. I would still like to understand why I could not make the wing by extruding it if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Yes. I removed them because I could not apply a mirror modifier in my later attempts. If this is the reason for the problem, why does it not affect the rest of the body, only the wings?

Comment: If u really wanna know - I think you have to upload your blend file so we can check it out.